# Repetition of image while scrolling in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to load images from the Internet using this adapter  i try to create the image and text display how can i fix this problem

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View v=convertView;
    if(v==null)
    {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        v=vi.inflate(Resourse, null);
        holder.pro_img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.pro_img);
        holder.pro_id=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pro_id);
        holder.pro_name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name);
        holder.pro_price=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pro_price);
        v.setTag(holder);           
    }else {
        holder=(ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    holder.pro_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    holder.pro_img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.pro_img);
    holder.pro_id=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pro_id);
    holder.pro_name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pro_name);
    holder.pro_price=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pro_price);
    v.setTag(holder);   
    new DownloadImageTask(holder.pro_img).execute(productdetails.get(position).getpro_img());
    holder.pro_name.setText(productdetails.get(position).getpro_name());
    holder.pro_id.setText("Product ID :"+productdetails.get(position).getpro_id());
    holder.pro_price.setText("Price"+productdetails.get(position).getpro_price());                 return v;        
}
```

Comment: the image disappears when i scroll back help me guys

Answer (score 1):

Use a third party library to handle image downloading, memory handling etc like Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) or Universal Image Loader (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

You'll run into less images, it handles stopping image downloading when the view is off screen and it handles loading images from cache so you don't have to keep making network calls.